# Is there any way to access Google Photos Desktop Uploader's "File Status" using command line?

Tags: command-line, google-photos

I would like to write a batch script which would tell me the Google Photos status of all the files in a folder. "File Status" dialog box doesn't even support drag-n-drop. Is there any way to access this "File status" feature using command line?